# If I hide something for mobile using mobile first, will Google see it as hidden?

Tags: css, seo, google-search

I have a text element on a page that needs to be hidden on mobile, but displayed on larger screens. Using mobile first, the way I'd do it is this:

```
.secondary {
     display:none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    .secondary {
        display:block;
    }
}
```

Would search engines like Google see this element as hidden and discount it or would they see the media query and assume it's page content?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on Pro Webmasters stackexchange for SEO questions.

Answer (score 0):

MobileFirst Platform apps are Mobile apps, thus it's got nothing to do with Google's search engine. It's an app and is rendered locally in your device.

Your question as-is makes no sense.

Comment: I think David is using the tag "mobilefirst" in the generic industry sense (i.e. responsive design), not in an IBM product sense.

Comment: I removed the misleading/wrong tag from the question.

Answer (score 0):

Google uses content displayed for desktop to compute mobile rankings. So your text content will be taken into account (more details about Mobile SEO in a [summary](https://seosummaries.com/expertise/mobile-site-seo-tips-strategy.html) I maintain).